# Draw lines from tab control headers to list box items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, itemscontrol

I am developing a c# application with WPF in which I have a tab control (with bottom aligned headers) and a items control under it.

I would like to draw some lines between the tab headers and items in my items control to help make it obvious what items can be found in what tabs. Preferably I would like some neat curvy lines to do this but for now I would settle with straight lines to get me on my way.

[image: Example layout]

The green lines in the above picture is what I would like to add but don't really know where I should use a jumping off point to get started on this, I suspect it is something along the lines of inspecting actual positions with some kind of converter, and spiting out path geometry to a canvas.

Comment: Do you have a static layout, or is it desirable to resize the tab headers and/or to resize/move the items in the `ItemsControl`?

Comment: Both the tabs and items are dynamic